# Postgresql not converting timezone correctly

Tags: postgresql, timezone, dst

I am building an application that needs to handle different timezones, including timezones with daylight savings time.  I am storing all the dates/times using Postgressql's timestamp with timezone data type, and all are stored in the UTC timezone (I modified the `timezone` entry in postgresql.conf).

Here is an example table that I have created:

```
CREATE TABLE category_city
(
category_city_id serial NOT NULL,
appt_start_time timestamp(0) with time zone,
appt_end_time timestamp(0) with time zone,
appt_days_of_week character varying,
CONSTRAINT category_city_pkey PRIMARY KEY (category_city_id )
);
```

I have been testing some conversions using the 'America\Edmonton' timezone.  Currently, this timezone is 6 hours behind UTC.  I have a timestamp in this table that has the value `1970-01-01 15:00:00+00`.

Now I perform this query:

```
SELECT appt_start_time at time zone 'America/Edmonton' as start
FROM category_city
```

This *should* give me the timestamp `1970-01-01 09:00:00+00`, but instead it gives me the timestamp `1970-01-01 08:00:00+00`, an offset of -7. which is the correct offset when not in DST, but is obviously not correct right now (DST is in effect).

I must be missing something because I'm sure I'm not the only one that needs to handle different timezones with DST.

The time on my server is correct, this is the output of the `date` command on Ubuntu:

`Wed Apr 30 17:11:59 MDT 2014`

Can anyone see something that I am overlooking, or has any experienced something similar and found a way to workaround it? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At `1970-01-01 09:00:00+00` the time at the timezone `'America/Edmonton'` was `1970-01-01 08:00:00` **regardless of when you ask**. If you want the time at a specific timezone you need to make it explicit:

```
select '1970-01-01 15:00:00+00' at time zone 'MST' as start;
        start        
---------------------
 1970-01-01 08:00:00

select '1970-01-01 15:00:00+00' at time zone 'MDT' as start;
        start        
---------------------
 1970-01-01 09:00:00
```

I guess it is easy to see above why that time at the `MDT` timezone will always be the same.

Comment: @Denis Ok I just copied without paying attention.

Comment: Ya, I figured as I was trying to make sense of the question.

Comment: That makes perfect sense.  I feel silly that I overlooked something like that, haha.  Thanks